# Selenium Webdriver(JAVA) Nested Elements

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How do I access a nested element without using xpath

this is how I would write it in Selenium WebDriver (Ruby)

```
@browser.find_element(:class, 'mapLock').find_element(:class => 'mapLockOverlay').click
```

But how would I write it in JAVA
I have tried:

```
browser.findElement(By.className("mapLock").findElement(By.className("mapLockDisplay").click
```

which I know is obviously wrong

Answer (score 8):

You're actually pretty close, just mind the brackets. I just separated things a bit.

```
final WebElement mapLockElement = browser.findElement(By.className("mapLock"));
final WebElement mapLockDisplayElement = mapLockElement.findElement("mapLockDisplay");
mapLockDisplayElement.click();
```

If you're doing it all on one line, it would be

```
browser.findElement(By.className("mapLock")).findElement(By.className("mapLockDisplay")).click();
```

Comment: Or even better, `browser.findElement(By.css(".mapLock .mapLock display")).click()`.

Comment: Indeed! Wasn't something that came to my mind, as I'm not a web developer most days, but a great solution nonetheless :)